# Highcharts - Sankey chart not displaying all the data when series font increased

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a simple sankey charts of highcharts. I am plotting it using a sample data.Every thing is working fine but here one small issue when I increase the font size of datalabels its not displaying all the data. When I hover only its displaying. Is there any solution for it. Here is the code below.I am also controlling the font size in export option.

### html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### script

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.from} to {point.to}, {point.weight}.'
        }
    },

        exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
       series: [{
         dataLabels: {
           style: {
             fontSize: "6px",
             fontWeight: "normal"
           }
         }
       }]
       }
      },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 5],
            ['Brazil', 'France', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'England', 1],
            ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['Canada', 'France', 5],
            ['Canada', 'England', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'France', 1],
            ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5],
            ['Mexico', 'England', 1],
            ['USA', 'Portugal', 1],
            ['USA', 'France', 1],
            ['USA', 'Spain', 1],
            ['USA', 'England', 5],
            ['Portugal', 'Angola', 2],
            ['Portugal', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['Portugal', 'Morocco', 1],
            ['Portugal', 'South Africa', 3],
            ['France', 'Angola', 1],
            ['France', 'Senegal', 3],
            ['France', 'Mali', 3],
            ['France', 'Morocco', 3],
            ['France', 'South Africa', 1],
            ['Spain', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['Spain', 'Morocco', 3],
            ['Spain', 'South Africa', 1],
            ['England', 'Angola', 1],
            ['England', 'Senegal', 1],
            ['England', 'Morocco', 2],
            ['England', 'South Africa', 7],
            ['South Africa', 'China', 5],
            ['South Africa', 'India', 1],
            ['South Africa', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Angola', 'China', 5],
            ['Angola', 'India', 1],
            ['Angola', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Senegal', 'China', 5],
            ['Senegal', 'India', 1],
            ['Senegal', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Mali', 'China', 5],
            ['Mali', 'India', 1],
            ['Mali', 'Japan', 3],
            ['Morocco', 'China', 5],
            ['Morocco', 'India', 1],
            ['Morocco', 'Japan', 3]
        ],
         dataLabels: {
           style: {
             fontSize: "30px",
             fontWeight: "normal"
           }
         },
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]

});
```

Comment: Hi @anguler-developer, Could you provide me with some live demo? In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4965/ everything seems to work correctly.

Comment: I saw your demo that is correct, below Brazil, Canada is also there that is not showing. I mean when I increase the font size of datalabels this problem is happening. On hover only it's visible. I need bigger font with all data visible.

Comment: Do you mean that some data labels are hidden, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4966/ ?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the data labels are hidden because they are too close to each other and overlap. To show all of them set:

```
dataLabels: {
  allowOverlap: true,
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4967/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.dataLabels.allowOverlap